# Nested Template and Template Infer Error

Tags: c++, templates

Code below does not compile. Line 14 and 15 are the problem and I don't know how to fix it. How can the templated function been altered to get this little example to run?

My compiler says:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make'
```

and

```
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template
      argument 'CONTAINER'
```

compiling this code:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename TYPE>
struct Node
{
    Node(TYPE & _value) : value(_value) {};
    TYPE value;
    typename std::vector<Node<TYPE>>::const_iterator first, last;
};

template < template <typename, typename...> class CONTAINER
         , typename TYPE
         , typename... ARGS >
Node<TYPE> & make ( Node<TYPE> & _node
/* not correct */ , typename CONTAINER<TYPE, ARGS...>::const_iterator _first
/* not correct */ , typename CONTAINER<TYPE, ARGS...>::const_iterator _last
                  , unsigned _k )
{
    if (std::distance(_first,_last) < _k)
    {
        _node.first = _first;
        _node.last = _last;
    }
    return _node;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned k = 3;
    std::vector<int> dataset;
    int i = 4;
    Node<int> node(i);
    node = make(node, dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), k);
}
```

Comment: This is confusing: `Node` contains a `vector<Node<>>::const_iterator` which `make()` wants to assign from `dataset.begin()` but `dataset` is a `vector<int>` not a `vector<Node<int>>`.  How are these compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename, typename...> class CONTAINER
```

Loosely speaking, this matches a template itself, like `std::vector`, that takes the requisite template parameters. It does not match a template instance, like `std::vector<int>`.

I see no particular need to get so nitty-gritty here. A simple

```
template <typename ITERATOR, typename TYPE>
Node<TYPE> & make ( Node<TYPE> & _node,
                    ITERATOR first, ITERATOR last, unsigned _k )
```

should work just fine here. If you do want to try to restrict the template parameters, in the manner that you were originally trying to do, the way to go is to declare this generic template, then try to define an appropriate specialization.

Comment: This solution won't work because ultimately OP is trying to assign a `std::vector<Node<int>>::const_iterator` to a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` within the function, and these types are not assignment compatible.

Comment: This would be the second issue here. But, insofar as the template substitution failure that was being asked here, this is the reason why.